# File writes per second

Tags: file

I want to log visits to my website with a high visits rate to file. How much writes to log file can I perform per second?

Comment: Can you clarify what additional functionality you need that's not provided by Google Analytics?

Comment: @Ilya, wWhat server are you using? Apache?

Comment: ok, i'll try to explain in details what i need. i have advertising network and i want to log banners shows to file and then upload them to mysql once per 5 minutes. banners shows has a rate about 50 per second

Comment: yes, apache, 8 core server with 4 gb of memory

Comment: 8 core with 4GB? Is that all? ;-)

Comment: o, sorry 16 gb on server

Comment: If you have 50 per second and you are flushing my MySQL every 5 minutes, you shouldn't have more than 15,000 at any one time. Why not keep them in memory and write to MySQL from there? You won't have nearly the same throughput bottlenecks as with writing to disk.

Comment: sorry, where in memory should i kepp them?

Comment: Keep them wherever you were planning to do the writes to disk. Sicne you are writing to disk and you aren't using your web server's standard logging mechanism, I presume that you must be planning to write a custom extension for the web server to do the logging that you want. A custom module can just as easily keep the information in a dynamically-allocated block of RAM as it can writing to disk.

Answer (score 8):

If you can't use Analytics, why wouldn't you use your webserver's existing logging system? If you are using a real webserver, it almost certainly as a logging mechanism that is already optimized for maximum throughput.

Your question is impossible to answer in all other respects. The number of possible writes is governed by hardware, operating system and contention from other running software.

Comment: i think that parsing is hard and long process

Comment: @Ilya: Not nearly as hard as trying to optimize file writes.  Perl exists primarily to do things like log parsing; there are other, more targeted options available as well, such as splunk.  Don't go nuts reinventing this wheel.

Comment: You can write custom logs (f.i. only to those URLs you're interested in, or in a specific format that doesn't include stuff you don't need such as User Agent), this can save a lot in parsing time. See CustomLog and friends in the Apache docs.

Comment: ok, but in some cases i need deduct banner shown, in other case - no, but in log all cases will be

Comment: Apache logging can be conditional, so you should be able to configure it such that a log entry is written only when the banner was shown (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html). How to do this exactly will depend on the conditions of showing the banner, but better create a new question if you need help with that since this one is supposed to be about file-writing performance.

Comment: There are hundreds of existing log parsers and analyzers, why not use one of those?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that, use [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) instead. You'd end up running into many problems trying to open files, write to them, close them, so on and so forth. Problems would arise when you overwrite data that hasn't yet been committed, etc.

If you need your own local solution (within a private network, etc) you can look into an option like [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) which operates off of crawling through your log files.

Comment: The richness of the information that is provided by Analytics is wonderful.

Comment: i know, but i need some other functionality

Comment: you just think you need your own logging system. if you really have a high volume site, you would know you don't want to log to the file system, you want to log to syslog on another machine, I recommend google analyitics as well, way better than anything you can cook up yourself

Comment: What *other* functionality could you possibly need that isn't already available in Analytics? Have you used Analytics before? It's enormous :)

Comment: llya, then look into a log-parser than can run through cron or something and insert the data into a mysql database for you.

Comment: Jonathan there are very good reasons to build you business not alone on Google Analytics. So your answer is not helpful at this point because it does not contribute to teh solution of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Or just analyze the Apache access log files. For example with [AWStats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWStats).

Answer (score 2):

If your hard disk drive can write 40 MB/s and your log file lines are approx. 300 bytes in length, I'd assume that you can write 140000 HTTP requests per second to your logfile if you keep it open.

Anyway, you should not do that on your own, since most web servers already write to logfiles and they know very good how to do that, how to roll the files if a maximum limit is reached and how to format the log lines according to some well-known patterns.

Answer (score 2):

File writes are not expensive until you actually flush the data to disk. Usually your operating system will cache things aggressively so you can have very good write performance if you don't try to `fsync()` your data manually (but of course you might lose the latest log entries if there's a crash).

Another problem however is that file I/O is not necessarily thread-safe, and writing to the same file from multiple threads or processes (which will probably happen if we're talking about a Web app) might produce the wrong results: missing or duplicate or intermingled log lines, for example.

Comment: Thread safety is exactly what I am wondering about having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

File access is very expensive, especially when doing writes.  I would recommend saving them to RAM (using whatever cache method suits you best) and periodically writing the results to disk.

You could also use a database for this. Something like:

```
UPDATE stats SET hits = hits + 1
```

Try out a couple different solutions, benchmark the performance, and implement whichever works fast enough with minimal resource usage.

Comment: I think that using a relational database for this purpose would be overkill and would likely result in some serious performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

If using Apache, I'd recommend using the [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html) utility supplied as a part of the standard kit.

We use this to allow rotating the server logs out on a daily basis without having to stop and start the server. N.B. Use the new "||" syntax when declaring the log directive.

The site I'm involved with is one of the largest on the Internet with hit rates peaking in the millions per second for extended periods of time.

**Edit:** I forgot to say that the site uses standard Apache logging directives and we have not needed to customise the Apache logging code at all.

**Edit:** BTW Unless you really need it, don't log bytes served as this causes all sorts of issues around the midnight boundary.

Comment: @Ilya, see @EarthMind's suggestion about awstats for an initial starting point. We do all sorts of analysis on the logfiles on a daily basis using a custom stats analyser which is run on a dedicated suite of machines, e.g. Sun5240's. The analyser is implemented in a mixture of executables  written in C and Perl scripts. This analysis process takes at least ten hours per day to run!

Answer (score 0):

Let Apache do it; do the analysis work on the back-end.