# fast site logging

Tags: mysql, logging

i'm need to log some visits on my site to mysql and then parse them, such visits rate is about 50 per second. inserting each request is veryslow and bad, what can you advise me?

Comment: What web framework? What version of Mysql? What do you need to log eventually? All the hits and where they came from etc, or just a count per time frame?

Comment: own framework, mysql 5.0, i need to log banners shows

Comment: One tip: MySQL's ARCHIVE storage engine is extremely fast for INSERTs, making it ideal for many logging applications. It doesn't allow DELETE or UPDATE, but those are usually not necessary for logging.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Archive

Comment: (wrong form field.. ) put a memcache or some other key-value store thats memory-backed between your server and your database, and write out all stuff just in a more decent interval. But, a good RDBMS is also built to work that way, so 50rq/s shouldn't bring it down ( at least not with your multi-core and 8g ram setup )

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001279/file-writes-per-second

Comment: @Jonathan, Ilya's question here is more heavily focused on MySQL than his previous question which concerned general web server logging and analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried queueing them on the server and then inserting multiple requests at a time?

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

Unless you really need statistics in real time, I'd seriously suggest logging the requests to disk and then trawling them later. Using Apache's rotatelogs utility let's you obtain logs for analysis on a daily basis at midnight or on an hourly basis at the top of the hour if you really need a quicker turnaround.

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can use INSERT DELAYED which is ideal for logging, as it queues the statement and returns control to the script immediately. I also agree with @Jordan for the ARCHIVE engine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having a table for the visits per day/hour/minute with your unit of time as a key and then just running inserts into that table with an [on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause.